# SQL Server Data Tools installed, can't create new project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I installed SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 from this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

I had VS2012 professional installed already and had been using it for a while. I have SQL server 2012 installed as well.
The Data Tools installation seemed to complete fine and I restarted, but when I open Visual Studio and try and create a new SSDT project it's not there.

From the how-to's I've read it seems like I should be able to go to New Project and there should be an SQL Server node under Templates that allows me to create a new SQL Server Data Tools project. 
Except I don't see that SQL Server selection.

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem today and installed the SSDT for 2012 and 2013 and nothing worked. What worked for me was to uninstall all VS 2012 programs and install the data tools from the SQL Server 2012 ISO. This installed VS 2012 with data tools and I was finally able to open Package.dtsx without any errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

On my VS2012 it looks like this in the New Projects menu: Installed -> Templates -> Business Intelligence -> SQL Server

On my VS2013 it looks like this in the New Projects menu: Installed -> Templates -> SQL Server

So, I have an extra level 'Business Intelligence' in VS2012 compared to VS2013, perhaps You have a similar setup.

Also, take a look at the Help -> About menu. You should see Data Tools in the list of installed products. Mine says version 11.1.31009.1.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah I checked under the BI node as well and it doesn't have the projects. Good tip about checking Help/About. I do see SQL Server Data Tools there though, so it looks like it is installed.
Thanks

Comment: OK, then I would do the ususal stuff: restart VS, check for updates to make sure I have the latest version, reboot, reinstall, and verify that my VS version/license supports SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

What about opening the SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio, connect to a SQL Server instance, right click on a database and select **Create New Project**. That should do the same as [File -> New Project]